# Type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String?' error when retrieving data from SQLite database in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, casting, riverpod, sqflite

I'm encountering a type casting issue when retrieving data from an SQFlite database in Flutter. The error message "type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String?' in type cast" is thrown at a specific line of code, even though the database returns the correct values and types. I suspect the problem lies in the mapping of data to my model class.

How can I resolve this issue and correctly parse the data from the database into my model?

Here is my `Model`class:

```
class Product extends DatabaseModel{

  @override
  int id;
  String name;
  String brand;
  double price;
  bool desirable;
  int marketId;

  Product(this.id, this.name, this.brand, this.price, this.desirable,
      this.marketId);

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'brand': brand,
      'price': price,
      'desirable': desirable,
      'marketId': marketId
    };
  }

  static Product fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Product(
      map['id'] as int,
      map['name'] as String,
      map['brand'] as String,
      (map['price'] as num).toDouble(),
      (map['desirable'] as int) == 1 ? true : false,
      map['marketId'] as int,
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my **generic** Repository method I am using to get the `Product`from the database:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> getByName(String name) async {
    final map = await dbProvider.db.query(
      tableName,
      where: 'name = ?',
      whereArgs: [name],
    );
    if (map.isNotEmpty) {
      return map.first;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

And at last, my `ProductScreen`where I am trying to retrieve the value from the database and show it in a List:

```
final productProvider = FutureProvider<Map<String, dynamic>?>((ref) async {
  final searchText = ref.watch(searchTextProvider);
  final repository = Repository<Product>("Product");

  if (searchText.isNotEmpty) {
    final result = await repository.getByName(searchText);
    return result;
  }
  return null;
});

final searchTextProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) => '');

class ProductScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ProductScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final productsAsyncValue = ref.watch(productProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Tela de Produtos'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            onChanged: (value) {
               ref.read(searchTextProvider.notifier).update((_) => value);
            },
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Pesquisar',
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: productsAsyncValue.when(
              data: (dataMap) {
                if (dataMap != null) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: dataMap.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var product = Product.fromMap(dataMap[index]);// Here is the error
                       return ListTile(
                         title: Text(product.name),
                         subtitle: Text(product.brand),
                       );
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text('Nenhum resultado encontrado');
                }
              },
              loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(),
              error: (error, stackTrace) => Text('Erro: $error'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried a couple of approaches where I did type casting to see if I could fix the error. I'm not sure if the problem is in my `Product` class, repository or how I'm trying to retrieve the data in my `ProductScreen`

I'm also trying to keep the `Repository`as generic as possible so other Model classes can also use it, thus eliminating duplicate code.

Comment: This stuff is so much easier with the new pattern matching.  Be sure to do the dart codelab on patterns and records.